# Admin panel: generate list of users for my app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I created an app, here she is: http://www.didlist.net, i got a few members, but the only way i can see a list of my members is my rails console with the command:

-User.all

What is the best way to create an admin panel to have a more detailled and ergonomic interface to see my members?

Big thanks :)

Jérémy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
rails g scaffold_controller User
```

This will create a scaffold controller for the `User` model.

Comment: Ok i'm quite new to ROR (i'm learning dev since 2 weeks), can you explain me what it means in other words ?

Comment: With scaffolding you can build a REST controller and views with one command. In this example, you create a controller and views for the existing model `User`. After that, you can browse to `/users` to view/edit/create/destroy users.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Zwippie. I launched the rails g scaffold_controller User command, then i tried to access to http://localhost:3000/users, but i ran to an error: No route matches [GET] "/users"

Rails.root:

Comment: You have to add the route `resources :users` to `config/routes.rb`. But that is all kind of basic Rails knowledge from the manual.

Comment: Thanks Zwippie i succeeded thanks to your help to create this page i can now acces /users but it only show: show edit destroy users, i can't see any informations about the users?

Answer (score 0):

Checkout active_admin, it is a very good solution for this purposes https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin. It has some mind blowing things but 99% of time does it's job

Comment: Thanks i'll try this out, i'll let u know :)

Comment: Ok i tried, but the thing is that i am using rails 4.0 and ruby 2.0. It looks like active_admin doesn't like this two version, when i'm trying to add the active_admin gem, bundle install went to an error.

Comment: September 29, 2013 update

The Rails 4 branch has been merged into master. Now all you need to do is specify:

gem 'activeadmin', github: 'gregbell/active_admin'

I use it both with rails 4 and ruby 2